# How to configure Jenkins StarTeam plugin?

Tags: hudson, starteam, jenkins

Jenkins (Hudson) has [StarTeam plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/StarTeam). How to configure it properly?

I have installed this plugin but when I build the project I get this error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/starbase/starteam/Folder

Machine is Windows Server 2008.
I have StarTeam SDK installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\StarTeam SDK 10.4` folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a hint on plugin documentation page:

> The plugin requires the StarTeam SDK, StarTeam extensions and jsafe libraries in Hudson's classpath. These files are included in the freely downloadable StarTeam SDK package from Borland (Micro Focus) , and may be installed by e.g. dropping them in Hudson's WEB-INF/lib directory.

Copy the folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\StarTeam SDK 10.4\Lib" to "C:\Jenkins\plugins\starteam\WEB-INF" (so there would be a *Lib* folder under *WEB-INF*), and restart Jenkins.

---

If you get "**Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform**" error:

Uninstall JRE (Java Runtime Environment) for Windows x64, install 32-bit version of JRE.