# Getting NoClassDefFoundError when trying to run Hudson Starteam task

Tags: hudson, starteam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to configure Jenkins StarTeam plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163763/how-to-configure-jenkins-starteam-plugin)

I'm using Hudson 2.0, Solaris 10 and the latest version of the Starteam plugin.  I'm trying to run the StarTeam task to checkout my project.  Sadly, I get this error ...

```
FATAL: com/starbase/starteam/Folder
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/starbase/starteam/Folder
at hudson.plugins.starteam.StarTeamSCM.checkout(StarTeamSCM.java:127)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1180)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:506)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:422)
at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1362)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:145)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.starbase.starteam.Folder
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
... 8 more
```

I have the starteam110.jar file (which contains the class in question) in my /apps/hudson/WEB-INF/lib directory as well as the fact I start Hudson by putting that file in my classpath ...

```
            <exec_method type="method" name="start" exec="/usr/bin/java -Xmx512m -DHUDSON_HOME=/apps/hudson/ -classpath /apps/hudson/WEB-INF/lib/starteam110.jar -jar /apps/hudson/hudson.war --prefix=/hudson" timeout_seconds="0"/>
```

How can I cure this error or troubleshoot further?  Thanks, - Dave

Comment: Does the StarTeam SDK you are using support Solaris?  I couldn't find docs for the latest version but as of the 2009 version it listed support for Unix but not specifically Solaris.  Could you find some of the example code using the SDK and try to execute it on that box to make sure it works outside of Hudson?